# Is it possible to create offline firebase app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, offline

I am trying to create a simple notetaking app(ios/android) with the ability to save text and pictures to cloud storage (am using firebase).

so the prototype works fine except when offline.

Firestore has offline capabilities, but Google sign-in does not allow silent-login authentication when offline. ([issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15796))

How can I solve this with just using firebase authentication?

One solution could be storing data offline in files [Files](https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files/) and then when online, Authenticate with firebase (run `googleSignIn.signInSilently()`) and push data to firestore.

Is there a simpler way to do this?